# RSA Data encryption and decryption on frontend and api error

Tags: python, typescript, rsa

I am trying to implement RSA encryption over frontend and API connection.
I have public and priavte keys generated for server. When client encrypts message using server's public key (which is accurate for sure) i cannot decrypt it and i get DecryptionFail error.

Public key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGJAoGBAI44vNec6AMkxwIz4uYLZW1/86sfcU85/01ySLWf6e3cNcBtpDOHjXAO
1XV77tCG2FMKueCMNL2/UQKFG2Zvb0DbPJqVwWxzVyHqGyleVMD6CBoySvFE5uYa
h8wFws0UciplMWPughlAlpyV/brxmMtzPVCZ00ZUSq75lZAWvIdvAgMBAAE=
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Private key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

(it will be changed)

I encode message in typescript using:

```js
crypto.publicEncrypt(serverPublicKey, Buffer.from(message, 'utf-8')).toString("base64")
```

Encoded message:
VeUTyDXorJjej4Vs0Mo7i3asYER4XyH4sdZkIfHu/E9WAnqgzWktCbin83NDMtIfvg/obRpjYykzYMmsyxfBkO17vDJK/MNiHTV86CMiJDVOJMJPnHtbrBLBmsW/LTx6mcTdOPLhauWw5t9UgyBCDE/isVitiRwhO0bGOUG+lPU=

Trying to decrypt message on API:

```py
decrypted_bytes = rsa.decrypt(base64.b64decode(encrypted_data), SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY)
```

I have tried using different hashing modules at frontend but none of them helped

Comment: You encrypted using OAEP padding with SHA1 for both hashes. Therefore, upon decryption, you must also specify that you are using OAEP adding with SHA1 for both hashes. When you do that, decryption succeeds. You need to specify which python crypto library you are using so that a proper answer can be written or the appropriate duplicate found.

Comment: The Python reference and the syntax used for decryption [`rsa.decrypt()`](https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/reference.html#rsa.decrypt) smell like Python-RSA. If this is true, decryption is not possible because this library does not support OAEP, see [issue #68](https://github.com/sybrenstuvel/python-rsa/issues/68). Solution: Use PKCS#1 v1.5 padding on the NodeJS side or another RSA library on the Python side that supports OAEP (PyCryptodome, pyca/cryptography, ...).